# Create mutating function on Array.prototype

Tags: javascript

For e.g.

```
var arr = [1,3];
arr.empty() // changes arr to [];
Array.prototype.empty = function(){
  this = []; // this throws error
}
```

Please help me understand, whats the workaround.

Comment: What part is not clear to you? @ Carcigenicate

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to mutate (remove) the contents of the array, instead of replacing it:

```js
Array.prototype.empty = function(){
  this.splice(0, this.length);
}

var arr = [1,3];
arr.empty();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whats the workaround?

First, the problem: You can't change the 'this' keyword. The solution is really simple!

Here:

```
Array.prototype.empty = function(){
    this.length = 0;
}
```

Since the array length is set to zero it can't hold any entries!

So the final code:

```
Array.prototype.empty = function(){
    this.length = 0;
}
var arr = [1, 3];
console.log(arr);
arr.empty();
console.log(arr);
```